# How to bring numpy on iMX6?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, arm, armv7

I am working on iMX6-quard armv7-a architecture. I need `numpy`, to run my python code on it.

The best option to install `numpy` is `pip install numpy`, but I don't have `pip` too. I tried to install `pip` like

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

but it's not working. I tried by downloading wheel from `https://gergely.imreh.net/wheels/numpy/`, but again I didn't get success to install `numpy`.

If anyone has done it successfully, please help me to do the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have a clue about your architecture but is it possible for you to `apt-get install` something? You can `apt-get install python-numpy` on most systems

Comment: Unfortunately `apt-get` is also not present in BSP linux on iMX6.

Comment: I see, take a look [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/building.html) for instructions on building `numpy` from source files, perhaps that'll help

Comment: I followed few commands from `https://github.com/imrehg/arm-wheels/blob/master/arch/armv7hf/2.7/Dockerfile` and able to install `pip`, but when I checking the version `pip --version`, I am getting error https://pastebin.com/gT4n3JYr `ImportError: No module named xmlrpclib`

Comment: That's probably the subject for another question

Comment: You can use buildroot or Yocto to easily prepare your Linux for iMX6. Then it will be quick to add python-numpy.